# Implement a [DllImport] like mechanism

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport, typeloadexception

Here's my problem: within a PCL library I'm going to call unmanaged code from a C++ DLL. That DLL comes in two versions (x86 and x64) and for performance reasons, the correct library should be referenced depending on the platform where the PCL library is embedded.

Since the `[DllImport]` attribute requires a constant string as the library name, this very convinient way renders useless, as the correct library is to be determined at runtime. There are some “hubby” ways to load the functions manually (`LoadLibrary`, `GetProcaddress` and `GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`) but I’m going to make it more convenient for the programmer.

So, declaring an external function is not the problem. Well, the C# compiler detects the external and worried about the fact, that with the missing `[DllImport]` attribute, the external might not be resolved when the type is loaded. Okay, I defined an attribute `[MyImport]` and placed it at the external declaration and bingo, at least the compiler was happy.

At runtime, I of course get a TypeLoadException becauce my external is indeed unresolved. That raises two questions:

1) Why is the compiler happy with any attribute?
Is there any magic from the loader with regard to using that attribute in order to resolve the pending external? This could straightforwardly done by providing an interface to be implemented by the attribute. This way the runtime would lookup the attributes of the external searching for those that implement the “magic” interface.

2) How can I catch the TypeLoadException in a way where I can implement my own loader?
That loader would iterate all externals from the given type, read the [MyImport] attribute and resolve the external this way.

Any idea out there if one of the two ideas can possibly be implemented or is there any other solution to the mentioned problem?

I appreciate English lessons though, but that actually isn’t what I’m asking for:-))

Christian.

Comment: C# or C++ pick one please. The mechanisms to realize plugins as you seem to want them are very different for these languages!

Comment: Are you commenting on the use of the tags? Well, I'm looking for a solution to import C++ methods into a C# type... wouldn't you agree that this has something to do with both - C++ and C#?

Comment: There's this [`PInvoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx) stuff IIRC. If you meant [tag:c++cli] you could probably have more convenient options.

Comment: I was thinking about C++/CLI but this doesn't solve the problem of having a 32/64 bit Version and the fact, that in a PCL I only understand at runtime on what platform the PCL is executing. Of course I may provide wrappers to all functions I'm going to use from the C++ DLL but this is tedious work...

Comment: This is all just wishful thinking.  The jitter resolves *extern*, it is only happy to recognize [DllImport] and does not have an extension mechanism to bolt in your own.  You cannot use PCL, getting the right DLL loaded is merely a deployment problem that you can also solve by pinvoking SetDllDirectory() to tell the OS where to look for the file.

Comment: Yeah, that’s obviously wishful thinking. I see where you’re going with the SetDllDirectory() – I just need to give the 32/64 bit version the same name but have the reside in different directories. At the beginning, I’ll have SetDllDirectory() to point the loader to the right one. Great. However, how can I make sure that SetDllDirectory() is called at the very beginning of the program? Consider, C# does not expose the concept of module initializers and so the only way in a “controlled” call by some sort of an Initialize() function that calls SetDllDirectory()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I went with the solution mentioned by Hans, further down in the comment section.

As he mentioned, the whole issue is rather a deployment problem and less something to be addressed with workaround development. So, I gave the two platform versions the same name and let them reside in different directories - like this:

```
SystemTera.MyPCL.dll
x86\SystemTera.Platform.dll
x64\SystemTera.Platform.dll
```

Upon startup, I point the loader to the correct platform version:

```
public static class Platform
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string pathName) ;

    public static void Setup()
    {
        if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
            SetDllDirectory("./x64/") ;
        else // default Win32
            SetDllDirectory("./x86/") ;
    }
}
```

When I further refer to the platform libraries, the loader/jitter does the correct job:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [DllImport("SystemTera.Platform.dll")]
    static extern void MyPlatformFunction() ;

    public void DoTheJob()
    {
        MyPlatformFunction() ;
    }
}
```

That's a fine solution using existing concepts provided by the Framework.

Comment: You could also put the setup method into the static constructor.